# CSS3 transition don't work in firefox

Tags: css, transition, background-position

In web-site ([www.kkbio.co.uk](http://kkbio.co.uk)) i created a script that fix navigation bar on top and the logo is changing to smaller version by CSS3 transition. It's working in google chrome, but in firefox it isn't. Other transitions don't work too. I don't know why) Help me please:)

for example:

```
.navbar-brand {
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 342px;
    height: 82px;
    margin-left: 15p‌​x;
    margin-top: 15px;
    -moz-transition: height 0.5s, background-position 0.5s, margin-top 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s, background-position 0.5s, margin-top 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: height 0.5s, background-position 0.5s, margin-top 0.5s ease;
    transition: height 0.5s, background-position 0.5s, margin-top 0.5s ease;
}

.fixed .navbar-brand {
    height: 74px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    background-position: 0 -82px!important;
}

<a class="navbar-brand" href="http://kkbio.co.uk/" style="background-image:url(http://kkbio.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/copy-logo1.png);"></a>
```

Comment: welcome to SO. Please post your script here - it is good practice to help us faster resolve your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've got a few problems here...

You've used `!important` which is almost always a bad sign, and you've used it twice on the same element, so which rule is ***more*** `!important`?

Avoid using `!important` whenever possible. In this case it looks like you can avoid it by using:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="http://kkbio.co.uk/" style="background-image: url(http://kkbio.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/copy-logo1.png);"></a>
```

rather than:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="http://kkbio.co.uk/" style="background:url(http://kkbio.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/copy-logo1.png);"></a>
```

**Firefox will fill in default values if you use shorthands** like `background` so, while Chrome reads:

```
background: url(http://kkbio.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/copy-logo1.png);
```

Firefox reads:

```
background: url(http://kkbio.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/copy-logo1.png) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/yPnuN/104/)**

Comment: thank you for the answer. I improved all mistakes, you write about. But it don't work anyway. Maybe i did smth wrong?)

Comment: @swat-web I added an example. It should help to get you on the right track